# ExtJs 3.4 numberfield sends string instead of null

Tags: string, extjs, null

I have a form with which I modify a record of a JsonStore. 
This is the config of the JsonStore:

```
reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
fields: [
    'item_ref',
    'item_type_code',
    {
        name:'order_by',                
        type: 'int'            
    }]
}),[ ... ]
```

I'm trying to modify the order_by field (numberfield) but If leave it blank it sends a string " "... 
I would aspect a json with the order_by field empty something like:

```
{
    item_ref: 16
    item_type_code: 1
    order_by:  
}
```

But I got this:

```
{
    item_ref: 16
    item_type_code: 1
    order_by:  ""
}
```

Comment: That's the writer that plays here, not the reader.

Comment: That's right. But I didn't find any suitable configuration.
I tryed to force type: "json"... but nothing changed.